Create folder hierarchy in Github for our team in organization
I wanted to create multiple folders within a folder (in GitHub) for our team. For instance, under my manager there are 5 colleagues, and each colleague may have multiple projects in hand.
So I wanted to create a folder at my manager level, and under that folder, 5 folders for each team member, where every team member can work on multiple repositories they are assigned on.
Or
is there any suggested way to create such tree without GitHub

You are supposed to have an organization (https://github.com/your-organization), then you'd have the different repositories. Each user has a different username, and will be able to work on any repo, assuming the corresponding permissions are there. I don't get what you want with the "subfolders"

What do you mean by "different folders"? Are you maybe referring to branches?
You can have a main branch, develop branch, and have each member to create a branch from that one and work on it, and proceed to merge the changes on pull requests.
But that's quite the reason why Github exists, so I'm not sure I'm getting your question right.

Looking for Organizational set-up. Thanks.

This can be achieved by organization as suggested by @olepinto. This feature is disabled by our administrator. Closing this questions.
